# DTED Level 3, 4 or 5

Tags: development, file-formats, specification, dted

Does the specification for DTED 0 - 2 also apply to 3 - 5? I know the finest resolution supported by spec MIL-PRF-89020B is 0.1 arc-seconds which I think would barely cover up through DTED level 4, right?  I'm guessing then that my code for reading DTED 0 - 2 using just the header information should still work for the later DTED levels but I have no way of proving this.

Anyone know where to download sample DTED Levels 3 and up? I could use that as well.

Thanks!
Matthew Hanna

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "official" standard beyond DTED2 (yeah, citation needed...). There is data beyond that, but acceptance of that data is patchy.

For a sample of DTED3, see http://www.falconview.org/trac/FalconView/downloads (Link 20 - DTED3 for the Boulder area).

Comment: Thanks! At least the sample level 3 DTED will help me find if my code for reading DTED Levels 0, 1, and 2 will pass for reading level 3.

Comment: @irtheman and, did it?